# App to push out gps coordinates to a http post

Tags: ipad, safari

Does anyone know of an App which runs on the iPad and periodically http posts your gps coordinates?  We have a web application which has gps functionality.  It is not a native app.  So the intent is to have the iPad App post the location to some server, and then our web server retrieve the location from that server.

Or, alternatively, is there a way to have the Safari Browser get the GPS from the device and post it (I thought this was not possible, hence my post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an app that does that not sure it is only iPhone or iPad also. It is called GPS Tracker, developer Philip Harzig. It does send the positions to the providers server and one can (with a password) look up the positions recorded on a website.

Also I am developing a similar app at the moment and don't see an issue of http posting it up to a server (at least not technically) also don't think it is an issue with Apple as long it is done openly and transparent to the user what is happening.